# Linker Error LNK2019 & LNK2001 on templated class files

Tags: c++, templates, implementation

I recently started using the template-features of C++.
Unfortunately, I think I did not quite understand how to write the implementation of a templated class. I got one templated class with implementation, and one templated class with a subclass that has an implementation. The compiler gives me those 2019 Linker errors on nearly all methods of both classes - And I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the way I implemented the templated classes.
When I looked up those errors, most of the time it occured when someone forgot to implement a method he had defined in the header, but I'm pretty sure that this is not the case here.

My code looks as follows:

```
//ResourceManager.h
#ifndef ResMan_H
#define ResMan_H

#include "Loader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template<class Res>
class ResourceManager {

private:
    std::map<int, Res*> resourceList;
    Loader<Res> * loader;

public:
    ~ResourceManager();
    ResourceManager(Loader<Res> * loader);
    void load(int key, std::string filePath);
    Res* request(int key);
    void unload(int key);
    void dispose();
};

#endif
```

Implementation:

```
//ResourceManager.cpp
#include "ResourceManager.h"
#include <assert.h>

template<class Res>
ResourceManager<Res>::~ResourceManager(){
    this->dispose();
}

ResourceManager<class Res>::ResourceManager(Loader<Res> * loader){
    this->loader = loader;
}

void ResourceManager<class Res>::load(int key, std::string filePath){
    unload(key);
    this->resourceList[key] = this->loader->loadFromFile(filePath);
}

Res* ResourceManager<class Res>::request(int key){
    assert(this->resourceList.find(key) == this->resourceList.end() && "Resource could not be found. Make sure to load it before requesting it.");
    return this->resourceList[key];
}

template<class Res>
void ResourceManager<Res>::unload(int key){
    if (this->resourceList.find(key) != this->resourceList.end()){
        delete this->resourceList[key];
        this->resourceList.erase(key);
    }
}

void ResourceManager<class Res>::dispose(){
    for(std::pair<int, Res*> kv : resourceList){
        delete kv.second;
    }
    resourceList.clear();
}
```

Loader.h

```
#ifndef Loader_H
#define Loader_H

#include <iostream>

template<class Res>
class Loader {

public:
    virtual Res* loadFromFile(std::string filePath);

};

#endif
```

TextureLoader.h

```
#ifndef TextureLoader_H
#define TextureLoader_H

#include "Loader.h"
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

class TextureLoader : public Loader<sf::Texture> {

public:
    sf::Texture* loadFromFile(std::string path);

};


#endif
```

Implementation

```
#include "TextureLoader.h"

sf::Texture* TextureLoader::loadFromFile(std::string path){
    sf::Texture* texture = new sf::Texture();
    texture->loadFromFile(path);
    std::cout << "Texture loaded" << std::endl;
    return texture;
}
```

Sorry for the long code, but even if the body of those functions should be irrelevant I rather post it since I'm not 100% that the error doesnt lie in that code.

Comment: @RaymondChen Isn't a duplicate. As I stated in my post, I tried to find a solution before creating this question, and I found the link you sent me too - Unfortunately it doesnt give me the answer to my problem. Or maybe I'm simply stupid, but I hope not.

Comment: templates need to be defined in the file they are declared in.

Comment: @NathanOliver I aready tried implementing it in the same file, but I still got the error. (Why is it that they can't be defined in another file tho? I mean, why can't there be a work around?)

Comment: If putting the in the header file did not help, then you need to share the full error message so that people can see exactly what is not defined.